# Not able to use query param with expressJs api in localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, postman

In my `index.js` file

```
app.use('/api/v1/users', userRouter)
```

In Router file

```
router.get("/:id", getUserDataById);
```

In postman:

My GET URL looks like this: `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users?id=120622`

Error it gives:

```
Cannot GET /api/v1/users
```

I think, this is how query param should be given according to the docs and tutorials i followed, but this error won't go away.

If i remove query, then other endpoints work perfectly.

I am not able to catch what's going wrong here.

I am stuck with this from last 2 days.
Just a hint to resolve this, will help me a lot.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly your `index.js` and `routes.js` file is fine now you just need to send request correctly see the req.params is different and the req.query is different

## First Way with (Query)

In postman:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users?id=120622
```

Your Index.

```
app.use('/api/v1/users', userRouter);
```

In Router file.

```
router.get("/", getUserDataById);
```

How did you get that id;

```
let id = req.query.id;
```

## Second Way with (Params) - Look at the postman URL carefully and at Route

In postman:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/120622
```

Your Index.

```
app.use('/api/v1/users', userRouter);
```

In Router file.

```
router.get("/:id", getUserDataById);
```

How did you get that id;

```
let id = req.params.id;
```

This is the two-way you can get your id, Let me know if you have any more questions and I'll try to clarify your points with more clarity.

Comment: hey Thanks for answer. But i get different kind of error now. I used Second way.  In Service or controller file, i get this output: console.log("Id: ", id); output: id=120622

Comment: I'm glad it's working for you. If it does, please accept the answer and upvote. Thanks, Buddy :)

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling API correctly inside the Postman. You should call it like this:

```js
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/120622
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. :)   But In Service or controller file, i get this output:  console.log("Id: ", id);  output:  id=120622

Comment: That's why my DB query is not giving anything, because id should be just '120622', not 'id=120622'

Comment: I am glad it helped you. Consider also upvoting and accepting my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

In the router file, what you are using is [Route Parameter](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters) where the valid URL would be `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/120622`. for your Postman api to work you should remove `:id` at router file

Comment: removing :id in router gave error. I had to remove in Postman URL. It's working. Thanks a lot for your quick answer. :)